# Displaying the corresponding elements of two lists together

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and I want to match the same index of 2 different arrays and send it to a file but I'm having issues when compiling. This is my idea:

```
interfaces= ['g0/0','g0/1','g0/2']
nameif = ['inside','outside','dmz']

for i in interfaces:
    for j in nameif:
        if interfaces[i]==nameif[j]:
            g.write ('\ninterface '+ i + j)
```

I'm expecting to see this in the file:

```
interface g0/0 inside

interface g0/1 outside

interface g0/2 dmz
```

But when I run it like that, it says `TypeError: list indices must be intergers or slice, not str`.

Any idea, how can I achieve this on Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you need two loops for this. Try a `zip` instead.

```
for x, y in zip(interfaces, nameif):
    print('interface {} {}'.format(x, y))
```

---

```
interface g0/0 inside
interface g0/1 outside
interface g0/2 dmz
```

---

As a tip, you should understand how the `for` works better. For example,

```
for x in interfaces:
     print(x)

g0/0
g0/1
g0/2
```

A `for` loop iterates over an iterator, not indices. If you want to iterate over both, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(interfaces):
     print(i, x)

0 g0/0
1 g0/1
2 g0/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'i' loop iterates the elements in the 'interfaces' list...and then you try to use those elements as an index, which you cannot do.

What you were probably wanting is a numeric loop, such as:

```
for i in range(len(interfaces)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over all indices and then find the matching ones. If you have some index `i`, you can just access the corresponding item from each list.

```
for i in range(len(interfaces)):
    g.write ('\ninterface '+ interfaces[i] + nameif[i])
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you're getting that error because you're trying to use `i` and `j` as indices while they are actually elements of the lists that you are iterating over, and hence of string type.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and explanation